# How to make transition in and out of headline in CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions

I was wondering about why my code doesn't transition **in** and also **out** and I could not find answers.
I am sure there is some mistake comparing to other codes witch working effect but it's difficult to find for me. It's my first post tho so sorry for "stupid question"

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: crimson;
  margin: 0 10% 20px 10%;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid crimson;
}

h1:hover {
  font-size: 45px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<h1>Simple Text</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to achieve something like this.

which is to apply that transition initially on `h1` and not only in `:hover`.

```css
     h1 {
            font-size: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            color: crimson;
            margin: 0 10% 20px 10%;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            border-bottom: 2px solid crimson;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        h1:hover {
            font-size: 45px;
        }
```

```html
<h1>Simple Text</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all correct but you only need to put the transition in the h1 and not in the h1:hover.

So of you change it to this, it should work:

```
h1 {font-size: 40px;text-align: center;color: crimson;margin:0 10% 20px 10%;padding-bottom: 15px;border-bottom: 2px solid crimson; transition: 0.3s;}
h1:hover {font-size: 45px;}
```